# Milliseconds and nanoseconds in time format

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new Date(currentTime); // if you really have long
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());
```

Is it possible to add milliseconds and nanoseconds to the date format ?

Comment: Hmmm... what does the documentation say?

Comment: Please learn to use the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Also note the existence of microseconds. There are 1 000 000 nanoseconds in a millisecond.

Comment: Also note that system clocks can rarely measure in the nanosecond range. Even the miliseconds won't be accurate.

Comment: `java.util.Date` works internally with millis stored in a `long` type. So I am afraid there is no smaller fraction than millis for something dealing with `Date`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add milliseconds by adding `SSS` at the end, such as the format will be `HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

There is no reference in the `SimpleDateFormat` to nanoseconds. Usually `System.nanoTime()` is used for performance debugging and not for display purposes.

Answer (score 6):

```
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(date);

"HH:mm:ss:SSS" //SSS stands for milliseconds
```

Check [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info

Comment: You probably want SSS, not SS. These are milliseconds, not centi-seconds.

Comment: @Dan: `SS` works fine too, but millis between 10 and 99 won't have a leading 0.

Comment: @GriffeyDog hmm, true, i tought `date` was Calender reference here :P

Answer (score 0):

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
```

This gave me output,

```
24:03:2014_18:24:09:890:2018826751601473
```