# What should be the format in SimpleDateFormat to print date like this - 01-JUN-20 08.55.27.577984000 AM UTC?

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I want to print the current date in this format - 
01-JUN-20 08.55.27.577984000 AM UTC. Tried lot of formats in SimpleDateformat but none is working. What is the right way to print like this?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If you could use `DateTimeFormatter` that would be better, and the pattern you need will be `"dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.n a z"` which is exactly what you need, nanoseconds and timezone included.

Comment: Close, @matteobarbieri. If the fraction of second is, say 0.001234, one `n` will result in `.1234000`, so wrong. I suggest `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a z", Locale.ENGLISH)).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` (just gave `01-JUN-20 10.40.44.076408000 AM UTC` on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

**SimpleDateFormat**

You can use the following pattern:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeFormatting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a Z");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String formatted = formatter.format(new Date(2015, 4, 4, 13, 7, 19)); //One example date
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

This will give the output `04-05-15 11.07.19.000 AM +0000` where `+0000` equals to `UTC`.

Explanation of the pattern `dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a Z`:

- `dd` = the day
- `MM` = the month
- `yy` = the year
- `hh` = the hour
- `mm` = the minute
- `ss` = the second
- `SSS` = the millisecond. There does not exist a reference to nanoseconds in `SimpleDateFormat` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607611/13634030) answer).
- `a` = to show AM/PM
- `Z` = to show the timezone

---

**Additional information**

Please note: `SimpleDateFormat` is deprecated. You should use `DateTimeFormatter`. One big advantage is that you can also have the nanoseconds (`n`).

One example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class TimeFormatting {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
   ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss.n a 'UTC'").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
   String timeDate = time.format(formatter);
   System.out.println(timeDate);  
  }    
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to have `UTC` instead of `+0000` with `SimpleDateFormat` you can use `dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSS a zzz` instead.

---

Comment: But, this prints the timezone in number +0000,-4000 ..like that..I want it to be printed like UTC,America/Montreal , IST etc

Comment: I just edited my answer. Does that answer your question?